# C# SOAP Middleware MessageEncoder.WriteMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, soap

I try to run this tutorial: [custom-asp-net-core-middleware-example](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/custom-asp-net-core-middleware-example/)

But the reponse message at the client say´s:

```
S

ystem.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network. See inner exception for more details.
 ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Name cannot begin with the '/' character, hexadecimal value 0x2F. Line 1, position 74.
   at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, XmlException exception)
   at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.VerifyNCName(String s)
   at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.ReadQualifiedName(PrefixHandle prefix, StringHandle localName)
   at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.ReadStartElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.Read()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.ReadStartBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, EnvelopeVersion envelopeVersion, Boolean& isFault, Boolean& isEmpty)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReceivedMessage.ReadStartBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage..ctor(IBufferedMessageData messageData, RecycledMessageState recycledMessageState, Boolean[] understoodHeaders, Boolean understoodHeadersModified)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage..ctor(IBufferedMessageData messageData, RecycledMessageState recycledMessageState)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.ReadMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, String contentType)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.ReadMessageAsync(Stream stream, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 maxBufferSize, String contentType, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpResponseMessageHelper.ReadChunkedBufferedMessageAsync(Task`1 inputStreamTask, TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

I´ve also encounterd a problem with the request-message so I´ve written my own RequestMessage but I´m not sure whether I should write my own ResponseMessage, because I do not know how it should be.

Also I´ve changed the OperationDescription to fit the tutorials code, may there be the problem?

```
public OperationDescription(ContractDescription contract, MethodInfo operationMethod, OperationContractAttribute contractAttribute)
    {
        Contract = contract;
        SoapAction = contractAttribute.Name ?? operationMethod.Name;
        Name = contractAttribute.Action ?? $"{contract.Namespace.TrimEnd('/')}/{contract.Name}/{Name}".Trim('/');
        IsOneWay = contractAttribute.IsOneWay;
        ReplyAction = contractAttribute.ReplyAction;
        DispatchMethod = operationMethod;
    }
```

Comment: The error message is very clear that Name cannot begin with the '/' character.

Comment: @Rena the problem was Namespace in response.